# C# Outlook doesn't load css in alternate view

Tags: c#, email, outlook

As in the topic. I use Outlook as email program, SmtpClient, and MailMessage to send email. I also add AlternateViews, like "text/calendar" (.ics file), and "text/html", which is a html document (I mean it has all tags:  `<html>,<head>,<body>`). The second alternate view (html), does not load css (css I situate in `<head><style> my css </style>`). The content of `<body>` is swap dynamically. The `MailMessage.Body` is `null`. When I one alternate view (only html, without ics file), css are load. I tried to add css as another alternate view and as attachment. It doesn't work. How to do that?

It works on Outlook Web App, but how to do that in Outlook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outlook uses Word for rendering HTML markup. You can read about supported and unsupported HTML elements, attributes, and cascading style sheets properties in the following articles:

- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 1 of 2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338201(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 2 of 2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338200(v=office.12).aspx)

Appointment items in Outlook use the RTF markup for bodies, not HTML. See the [RTFBody](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861303(v=office.15).aspx) property which returns a Byte array that represents the body of the Microsoft Outlook item in Rich Text Format.

```
Sub GetRTFBodyForMeeting()  
 Dim oAppt As Outlook.AppointmentItem  
 Dim strRTF As String  
 If Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem.Class = olAppointment Then  
   Set oAppt = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem  
   strRTF = StrConv(oAppt.RTFBody, vbUnicode)  
   Debug.Print strRTF  
 End If  
End Sub
```